# In bash script, why do we need a back slash '\' before a command?

Tags: bash

I have encountered a bash script that has a back slash '\' immediately precedes a command. Could someone explain what the '\' is for? Thank you.
E.g.:

```
PATH='/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin'
\export PATH
```

Comment: It causes aliases and shell functions to be bypassed

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl for editing my question. Thanks jordanm for answering my question.